# Reverse normalization (Keras/Math)

Tags: python, math, keras, normalization

I'm trying to reverse this formula, but my math skills are not sufficient.

```
# (1 / v) = A small scaler because for some features we want 0.5 as max and not 1.0 as max

ds_min, ds_max = min(ds), max(ds)

normalized_ds = ((ds - ds_min) / (ds_max - ds_min)) / (1 / v)
```

I found this post ([How do you de-normalise?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45257856/how-do-you-de-normalise)) that solves part of the equation.

I have reached this far using the above link:

```
denormalized_ds = normalized_ds * (ds_max - ds_min) + ds_min
```

But i think i'm missing the last part regarding: "(1 / v)"

My logic tells me that i need to reverse division to multiplication, but i'm unsure where to put it in the equation to get the correct numbers.

Any help appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's just a matter of isolating ds in the first equation. Simply multiply by (1 / v) just after normalized_ds. So: denormalized_ds = normalized_ds * (1 / v) * (ds_max - ds_min) + ds_min.

Answer (score 0):

I think i managed to solve it myself through trial-and-error.

```
denormalized_ds = normalized_ds * 1 / v * (ds_max-ds_min) + ds_min
```